# CSS font-spacing issue with Calibri and the letters "ti"

Tags: html, css, fonts, ligature

I'm starting a website build for a small business that uses Calibri as the primary font for their branding and I have come across an issue with using this font in certain web browsers.

In Google Chrome and Opera, the letters "ti" appear to be joined.  When I apply some `letter-spacing`, they will not separate.  This doesn't happen in Mozilla Firefox or Microsoft Edge.

Is there an issue with the font, or is it the browser?
Is there anything I can do to fix it?

I've created a snippet for testing (or you can test at https://codepen.io/whitenoise83/pen/KyXWWL)

```css
#site-title {
  font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima,  Arial, sans-serif !important; 
  color: #e00b00; 
  font-size: 6em; 
  font-weight: bold;
  /*letter-spacing: 0.25em;*/
}
```

```html
<span id="site-title">Audiomation</span>
```

Comment: It's probably a ligature..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never seen that but after some search :
Maybe a font ligature option to choose ?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-ligatures

Hope its help ;)

Comment: Setting `font-variant-ligatures: none;` seems to have done the trick.  Thanks to you and xs0's comment.

Comment: Since this was an easy one, I'm marking the answer that came in first as correct.  I'd never experienced this ligature issue before - today I learned something new.  Cheers!

Comment: I also learned something, maybe saved precious time in the future ^^

Answer (score 3):

You can use `font-variant-ligatures: none;` in your CSS to prevent the browser using special *ligature* characters for some combinations of characters/letters.

See also this article: http://www.cssportal.com/css-properties/font-variant-ligatures.php

```css
#site-title {
  font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima,  Arial, sans-serif !important; 
  font-variant-ligatures: none;
  color: #e00b00; 
  font-size: 6em; 
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
```

```html
<span id="site-title">Audiomation</span>
```